# Residence permit

Tags: germany, netherlands

I am married to a dutch national and have a permanent dutch residence permit. I am planning to move to Germany with my wife where we both will work and i will enroll in a university for my masters. Can anyone tell me after moving there what legal requirement we need to do. Do i a non eu spouse having a dutch residence permit need to apply for German residence permit ? or any other legal requirement we need to do

Answer (score 1):

You are covered by the [freedom of movement](https://www.bmi.bund.de/EN/topics/migration/law-on-foreigners/freedom-of-movement/freedom-of-movement-node.html) EU law.

[The ministery of the interior says](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/DE/themen/migration/freizuegigkeit/freizuegigkeit-liste.html) you basically only have to register your new residence (as every German would have to do, too, when they move inside Germany) with your local "Meldebehörden" in the city you move to. That would be the "Ordnungs-Amt", the civil administration office. They will make sure the foreigners office gets all the documents they need.

You may need to provide proof of what you claim (that would mean your passports, a marriage certificate at least one work contract and/or sufficient funds) but that's just a formality. There is no proceedings or checks, *you already have the permission* by virtue of your wife's nationality, all you need to do is fill the paperwork.

Comment: Syed Kazim will need to get an *Aufenthaltskarte.*  The page you link to applies only to EU citizens.  There are additional requirements for their non-EU family members.

Comment: @phoog actually the page does apply. The *Aufenthaltskarte* will be issued during the process of registration. **Family members, regardless of their citizenship, accompanying or joining an EU citizen who satisfies these conditions also have the right of residence for more than three months.**

Comment: @phoog better stated: **after** the process of registration registration, since the registration is a prerequirement forbthe issuing.

Comment: "They will make sure the foreigners office gets all the documents they need." - don't rely on that.  The *Einwohnermeldeamt* at my local *Gemeinde* did **not** forward my details on to the *Ausländeramt* at the *Kreis*.  The situation was complicated by the fact that we had actually registered 10 years earlier when we bought the house, and I was just telling her that I had now moved in permanently.  Nonetheless, I would contact the *Ausländeramt* / *Ausländerbehörde* myself to make sure they know.

Comment: Martin is definitely right.  Just because something *should* happen, does not mean it actually does. I have seen some *ridiculously* stupid errors (for example giving a year of birth as 197 where it should be obvious to anybody that a digit is missing) when dealing with German "Amts". Better double check and *make sure* it's handled properly.